# How to revise a jpeg image's DQT?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a noob about Python, my class's homework is to realize F3 steganography algorithm. Now I get the quant blocks with information, but I don't know how to create a jpeg image. I wonder if there are any library that can read and revise a jpeg image's DQT and retain the original header and so no? If not, what can I do?

I've searched this kind of library for a long time, but the libraries or codes I found are too difficult to understand or use :(

Comment: Now your are looking for someone doing your homework? :-) Be more specific. Drill deeper to ask questions not easily copied from many tutorials.